# Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V, W$ be nonzero spaces over a field $F$ and suppose that a set $B=\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ subset of $V$ has the following property:
For any vectors $w_1,....,w_n$ as the element of $W$, there exists a unique linear transformation $T:V\to W$ such that $T(v_i)=w_i$ for all $i=1,...,n$.
Prove that $B$ is a basis of the space $V$.

I'm not very sure how to do it but here is my attempt to the question.
**First I prove that $B$ is linearly independent.**
Let $c_1,...,c_k$ be constants such that $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+....+c_kv_k=0$.
Apply the linear transformation of $T$ to both sides:
$c_1(T(v_1))+....+c_k(T(v_k))=0$, $c_1w_1+.....+c_kw_k=0$.
Since $w_1,...,w_n$ are basis for $W$, so it is linearly independent.
So we deduce that $c_1=c_2=....=c_k=0$.

But I'm not very sure how to prove that $B$ spans $V$.
Thanks all for the help:)

Comment: How are you sure that you can choose $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\}$ to be a basis? There may not be any $n$-element basis in W.

Comment: Oh yeah, then what would you advise me to do??

Comment: I have just written up an answer that should guide you to the proof.

Answer (score 2):

**Linear Independence.**

You'd have to manipulate the "*any*" part of the hypothesis: given any set of $n$ vectors in $W$, you get a unique linear map $T: V \to W$ such that $T(v_i) = w_i$.

The case $n=1$ is easy to see: if $\{v_1\}$ was linearly dependent, then, $v_1 = 0$. But, then, there cannot be a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, if we chose $w_1 \neq 0$ (such a choice is possible, since $W$ is a non-zero vector space).

Assume that $n > 1$, and that there is a linear dependence: without loss of generality, we may assume that $v_n$ is in the linear span of $\{v_1, \dots, v_{n-1}\}$.

$$v_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} c_i v_i$$

Now, deliberately choose, $w_n$ so that $w_n \neq \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} c_i w_i$ (you can always do this, modulo some edge cases!). This should help you finish the proof.

*Exercise.* Decipher those edge cases and handle them separately. (I'll write this up neatly in a bit.)

**Spanning.**

To show that $B = \{v_1, \dots, v_n\}$ is a spanning set, we may proceed by contradiction: you may extend this linearly independent subset $B$ to a basis $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$.

Now, if $\mathcal{B} \neq B$, defining $T$ arbitrarily on the set $\mathcal{B} \setminus B$, will give you *a lot* of linear transformations that agree on $B$. This contradicts the uniqueness of $T$.

You may want to flesh this argument for completing the proof.

Comment: Hi, I still don't get why contradicting the uniqueness of T can prove that B spans V?

Answer (score 2):

To prove **linear independence**, let $0 \ne w \in W$, and suppose
$$
a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_n v_n = 0.\tag{comb}
$$
For each $i$, consider the linear map $T_i$ such that $T_i(v_i) = w$, and $T(v_j) = 0$ for $j \ne i$. Applying $T$ to (comb), you get 
$$
a_i w = 0,
$$
so $a_i = 0$ for all $i$, and you have proved the $v_i$ to be linearly independent.

To prove that they **span** $V$, there's nothing better than the argument of @KannappanSampath. Simply note that if $\langle B \rangle$ is a proper subset of $V$ (so that there is $v_0 \in V \setminus \langle B \rangle$), then any linear map $T$ defined on $v_1, \dots, v_n$ can be extended by choosing an arbitrary value for $T(v_0)$. (And there are at the very least two possible values for it, that is $0$ and $w$.)

Comment: Clever proof for the linear independence. I did not think along your lines. Thank you for writing it up.